# AlienVault OSSIM - Editing Mobile Web Application

Tags: mobile, web

As Alienvault OSSIM has a mobile web version, have any programmers here edited the HTML code for the OSSIM mobile web version? If so, how do you do it?

I understand it is open source but I am not sure where to locate the files for it as I am pretty bad at editing open source code. Also, I do not want to crash my current OSSIM system which is up and running fine. :D

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To edit html, php code for ossim go to this directory

```
/usr/share/ossim
```

they are 7 directory

the most important are www and include